# Android Game - Drawing text on top of image

Tags: android, android-view, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I'm building an Android game which consists of a card as background.

What I need to do is to draw text on top of the image at runtime (each second or when a special event arises).
But I need to draw the text at specific positions of the image, let's say: if the image is 123x245, let's draw the text at (2, 3).
What I've done so far is to write the text onto the image (as a Bitmap) and assign that new Bitmap to the `ImageView`, but the performance is very bad.

So, what solution do you suggest in order to do this: `CustomView`, `SurfaceView`, etc?

Thank you.

Comment: A custom View would provide some advantages over ImageView (e.g. hardware-accelerated rendering). Right now you're using software rendering to generate an off-screen Bitmap, then providing the updated Bitmap to a View intended for the display of static images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend you `ImageView` and use `Canvas.drawText` method in `onDraw` to draw the text above any image set into `ImageView`. Don't forget to call `drawText` after `super.onDraw` call otherwise your text would be drawn below `ImageView`'s image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Bitmap addTextToBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    Paint p = new Paint();

    p.setTextSize(100);  // textSize
    p.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));  // textColor
    c.drawText("Your Text", POS_X, POS_Y, p);  // textPosition
    b = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true); 
    return b;
}
```

For example:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(addTextToBitmap(imageView.getDrawable().getBitmap()));
```

Comment: That's the approach I tried, and it took too much time (the process of copying the image and creating the canvas and paint)